# Git Submodules acting strangely

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a super project,
I have added a submodule to the project,
I have renamed the directory that the submodule is in and edited the appropriate files.

Anyway,

After doing a large amount of work I have `cd`'d into the submodules directory,
And running `git status` I get these lovely messages informing me that I have deleted one of my folders, and by association all the contents and apparently added the changes too so they are ready for commit. I don't recall doing this.

Yet, If I jump into my file browser, the files are sitting right there.
Now these files include some files I have also modified, but the modifications don't show up in git status, as as far as git is concerned I have deleted the folder.

So, the next one is,

I if I do `git pull` I get a message informing me that the pull will overwrite the changes in the files that I mentioned I had changed. yet do not show up in git status and that I should commit or stash the files.

But, running `git add /path/to/file.ext` I get `fatal: pathspec 'path/to/file.ext' did not match any files` Which makes sense since git thinks I have deleted the folder.

What is going on here?

I guess I could use `git reset HEAD path/to/file.ext`.

But what is that going to do the my changes that I have made to the so called deleted files?

Also,
from inside the submodule, if I call `git add <path to folder inside submodule>` on a directory that was not there when I pulled the submodule initially then I get `fatal: '<path to folder inside submodule>' is outside repository`

Comment: This is expected behaviour. submodule does not work as good as svn external. Read the doc again.

Comment: Which doc are you referring to?